# Difficulty with using sec-ch-ua-platform-version request header for Windows 11 detection

Tags: web, browser, user-agent

I'm currently facing a problem in which I am using User Agent hints in determining the Operating System that a user is using from my app which is using Angular 11. The request header I want is 'sec-ch-ua-platform-version'.

User Agent Client Hints should be supported by Chrome 95+ and Edge 94+ and the browser in which I'm testing my app on is Chrome version 110 which supports User Agent Client hints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/how-to-detect-win11

The closest named header that I see from the network requests using Chrome is 'sec-ch-ua-platform'.

Here is an image from my network tab in dev tools: [Request Headers Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTWXd.png)

What I attempted to do is use meta tags in my index.html file in my Angular solution as suggested of this doc. However, I am still not seeing 'sec-ch-ua-platform-version' appear as a Request Header in my network requests.

https://docs.scientiamobile.com/guides/implementing-useragent-clienthints

```
<meta http-equiv="Critical-CH" content="sec-ch-ua-platform-version">
<meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="sec-ch-ua-platform-version">
```